# Get a cell value of table for each selected row?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to get a single value of cell per row on a table when a checkbox of this row is selected and get all values of all rows when the "Select all" checkbox is selected too.

I try to do this: A table with sub-table inside of each rows. So, I try to when the checkbox "Select All" y clicked, all the checkbox inside of sub-table the row that i clicked be marked and get the values of each rows.

All this in **Javascript** or **TypeScript**

this is my html:

```
<div class="table-responsive row col-md-12" style="margin-top: 3.5%; margin-bottom:1%;  border-bottom: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px;">
<table class="table table-hover tablaReclamaciones"  > 
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>No.</th>
      <th>Alias</th>
      <th>Exp. Date</th>
      <th>Past Deu</th>
      <th>Current Balance</th>
      <th>Mount to pay</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="containerCheck"> Select All
          <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>001</td>
      <td>My Home</td>
      <td>10/12/2018</td>
      <td>2500</td>
      <td>5000</td>
      <td>7500</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="7">
        <div class=" row col-md-12" style="background: rgb(243, 243, 243); margin-left: 0.15%;">
          <div class="row col-md-12 " style="color: rgb(253, 120, 43);">
            <h5 class="pull-left" >Details</h5> 
            <h5 class="pull-right arrowDown"  id="2222" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#' + r.nocontracto"  ><i class="test fa fa-chevron-down "></i></h5>
          </div>

          <div id={{ r.nocontracto }} class="table-responsive row col-md-12  "  style=" margin-top: 1%;" >
            <table class="table table-hover" style="background: rgb(243, 243, 243)">
                <thead>
                  <th></th>
                  <th>No. Reference</th>
                  <th>Invoice Date</th>
                  <th>Exp Date</th>
                  <th>Balance</th>
                  <th></th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr *ngFor="let b of r.billing" id="billDetails">
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" class="checkInside" name="invoiceCheck" onclick="singleRow()">
                    </td>
                    <td>123456</td>
                    <td>22/12/2018</td>
                    <td>12/01/2018</td>
                    <td>5250.00</td>
                    <td>
                      RD$ <input type="text" id="amountInput">
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr *ngFor="let b of r.billing" id="billDetails">
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" class="checkInside" name="invoiceCheck" onclick="singleRow()">
                    </td>
                    <td>123456</td>
                    <td>22/01/2018</td>
                    <td>12/02/2018</td>
                    <td>400.00</td>
                    <td>
                      RD$ <input type="text" id="amountInput">
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr *ngFor="let b of r.billing" id="billDetails">
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" class="checkInside" name="invoiceCheck" onclick="singleRow()">
                    </td>
                    <td>123456</td>
                    <td>22/02/2018</td>
                    <td>12/03/2018</td>
                    <td>2600.00</td>
                    <td>
                      RD$ <input type="text" id="amountInput">
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Total:

Javacript code (For get the value of a single row, but don't work):

```
function singleRow() {
let row = document.getElementById('billDetails');
let cells = row.getElementsByTagName('td');

let inputVal = document.getElementById('amountInput').value;

if(!inputVal) {

} else {
    console.log('Columna de Input: ' + inputVal);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: For starters you can't repeat element ID's in a page. They are unique by definition. Using native `onclick` and doing a dom search for this is totally the wrong approach in an angular app. Work with your component data that generates that table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following way in vanilla JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('change', function(){
    if(this.id == 'selectAll'){
      var trList = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tbody tr'); 
      console.clear(); //clear the console
      trList.forEach(function(tr){
        tr.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(function(td){
          console.log(td.textContent.trim())
        });
      });
    }
    else{    
      console.clear(); //clear the console
      var tdList = this.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes;
      tdList.forEach(function(td){
        console.log(td.textContent.trim())
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive row col-md-12" style="margin-top: 3.5%; margin-bottom:1%;  border-bottom: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px;">
<table class="table table-hover tablaReclamaciones"  > 
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>No.</th>
      <th>Alias</th>
      <th>Exp. Date</th>
      <th>Past Deu</th>
      <th>Current Balance</th>
      <th>Mount to pay</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label class="containerCheck"> Select All
          <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
        </label>
      </td>
      <td>001</td>
      <td>My Home</td>
      <td>10/12/2018</td>
      <td>2500</td>
      <td>5000</td>
      <td>7500</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="7">
        <div class=" row col-md-12" style="background: rgb(243, 243, 243); margin-left: 0.15%;">
          <div class="row col-md-12 " style="color: rgb(253, 120, 43);">
            <h5 class="pull-left" >Details</h5> 
            <h5 class="pull-right arrowDown"  id="2222" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#' + r.nocontracto"  ><i class="test fa fa-chevron-down "></i></h5>
          </div>

          <div id={{ r.nocontracto }} class="table-responsive row col-md-12  "  style=" margin-top: 1%;" >
            <table class="table table-hover" style="background: rgb(243, 243, 243)">
                <thead>
                  <th></th>
                  <th>No. Reference</th>
                  <th>Invoice Date</th>
                  <th>Exp Date</th>
                  <th>Balance</th>
                  <th></th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr *ngFor="let b of r.billing" id="billDetails">
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" class="checkInside" name="invoiceCheck" onclick="">
                    </td>
                    <td>123456</td>
                    <td>22/12/2018</td>
                    <td>12/01/2018</td>
                    <td>5250.00</td>
                    <td>
                      RD$ <input type="text" id="amountInput">
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr *ngFor="let b of r.billing" id="billDetails">
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" class="checkInside" name="invoiceCheck" onclick="">
                    </td>
                    <td>123456</td>
                    <td>22/01/2018</td>
                    <td>12/02/2018</td>
                    <td>400.00</td>
                    <td>
                      RD$ <input type="text" id="amountInput">
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr *ngFor="let b of r.billing" id="billDetails">
                    <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" class="checkInside" name="invoiceCheck" onclick="">
                    </td>
                    <td>123456</td>
                    <td>22/02/2018</td>
                    <td>12/03/2018</td>
                    <td>2600.00</td>
                    <td>
                      RD$ <input type="text" id="amountInput">
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @FelixAVeras, you are most welcome. Glad that it worked:)

Answer (score 0):

A sample solution in javascript:

```html
<label>A small sample code</label>
 <br> <input type="checkbox" name="all" onchange="allChecked(this)"/> <label>check all</label>
<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="child"   onchange="showVal(this)"/>
     <label>Strongly disagree</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="child"   onchange="showVal(this)"/>
     <label>Somewhat agree</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="child"   onchange="showVal(this)"/>
     <label>Strongly agree</label> 

 
 <script>
 function showVal(chk) {
   if(chk.checked){
    alert(chk.checked);
     // traverse the dom elements and get values of the cell you need
          
    }
       
 };
 function allChecked(chk){
  var childChks = document.getElementsByName("child");
     
  for(var i =0 ;i <  childChks.length; i++){
     childChks[i].checked =chk.checked;
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ES6 version (useful for [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the event targets efficiently). Instead of attaching change listeners to each checkbox element it uses ["event propagation"](https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/) to capture events as they bubble up the DOM.

Note: that I've reduced your HTML example down to the core parts, and updated your ids to classes (ids have to be unique, classes do not).

```js
// Grab the selectAll checkbox and add an eventListener to it
const allCheckbox = document.getElementById('selectAll');
allCheckbox.addEventListener('change', selectAll, false);

// Grab the amountInput elements 
const amountInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.amountInput');

// Grab the "inner" table and add an event listener to it
// The function attached to this listener will capture events as they
// bubble up from the checkboxes
const inner = document.querySelector('.inner');
inner.addEventListener('change', selectSingle, false);

function selectSingle(e) {

  // Grab the type and checked property from the element attached to the event,
  // and also the parentNode of its parentNode (the row element)
  const { type, checked, parentNode: { parentNode } } = e.target;

  // If the element is a checkbox and the checkbox is checked
  // (we don't want to return a value if the user has unchecked the box...)
  if (type === 'checkbox' && checked) {

    // Find the amountInput child element in that row,
    // and grab its value
    const { value } = parentNode.querySelector('.amountInput');
    console.log(value);
  }
}

function selectAll(e) {
  
  const { type, checked } = e.target;

  // If it is checked `map` over the amountInput elements
  // and return an array of their values
  if (checked) {
    const values = [...amountInputs].map(input => input.value);
    console.log(values);
  }
}
```

```html
<label class="containerCheck"> Select All
  <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
</label>

<table class="inner">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkInside" /></td>
      <td>RD$ <input type="text" class="amountInput" value="432" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkInside" /></td>
      <td>RD$ <input type="text" class="amountInput" value="12222" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkInside" /></td>
      <td>RD$ <input type="text" class="amountInput" value="324" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="out"></div>
```